# Trigonometry of bi-occular vision (just the geometry)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was reading an old complicated article on bi-occular vision in a dark room.

The experiment in short :

A test person is sitting in a completely dark room with two fixed lightbulbs at eye hight, the test person instructs an helper carrying a third light bulb so that the helper positions himself on the midpoint between the two fixed lightbulbs.

and I was interested in the geometry of this experiment.

Geometricly it abstracts to:

We have 5 points (A,B, M, L and R) on a plane
(L and R representing the eyes of the testperson,  A and B the fixed lightbulbs and M the lightbulb of the helper)

Given are:

- M is the midpoint of AB
- the angles $\angle ALR $ and $\angle BLR $ (the vieuwing angles of the left eye of the testperson)
- the angles $\angle ARL $ and $\angle BRL $ (the vieuwing angles of the right eye of the test person)

What are the angles $ \angle MLR$ and $\angle MRL $ ? (the vieuwing angles of point M)

If I am correct there is no need to know the distance LR, but feel free it as $e$ when needed.

for the real experiment the distance e (LR) is much shorter than all the other distances, but I think again that this is also not important.

Comment: Please, for a geometrical question, provide a sketch: it is so easy using e.g., Geogebra.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the importance of the given details wrong..Actually, the fact that

> LR is much shorter than all other distances

is the key point..

Using your notations,

Define $D$ to be the midpoint of $LR$.Consider $LR$ not perpendicular to line $BMA$.Drop a perpendicular from L line $BMA$ name it $Q$. Join $MD$ and $ML$ and $MR$.

$$\tan\angle QLR\simeq \angle QLR={LR/2\over MD}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(\angle QLR=\angle DMR \simeq very small\right)$$

$$\angle BLQ=\angle BLR - \angle QLR =\angle BLR- {LR/2\over MD}$$

Similarly

$$\angle ALQ=\angle ALR - \angle QLR =\angle ALR- {LR/2\over MD}$$

$$LQ\times\tan\angle MLQ ={LQ\times\tan\angle BLQ + LQ\times\tan\angle ALQ \over 2}$$

$$\angle MLQ =\tan ^{-1}\left({\tan \left( \angle BLR- {LR/2\over MD}\right)+\tan \left( \angle ALR- {LR/2\over MD}\right)\over 2} \right)$$

And $\angle MLR=\angle MLQ + \angle QLR$

PS: If $MD$ is not given, then it must be assumed that ${LR/2\over MD}\simeq 0$.